# How to change that " Fsharp don't auto "\n" "

Tags: f#

I'm coding a problem in : 
    https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-mingling/problem

But I don't know how to change that **" Fsharp don't auto "\n" "**
This is my code :

```
open System
let mutable p = Console.ReadLine()
let mutable q = Console.ReadLine()

let ans = ResizeArray<char>()
let mutable n = p.Length

for i in 0..(n-1) do 
    ans.Add(p.[i])
    ans.Add(q.[i])
ans |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn("%c") x)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Tried `printf`? `printfn` the n suffix implies new line `\n`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `printf` instead of `printfn` to avoid automatically adding a new line.

In general it's better to move side effects like printing to the edge of your program so that you only need to print once at the end. For example:

```
Seq.map2 (fun c1 c2 -> String[|c1; c2|]) p q
|> String.concat ""
|> printfn "%s"
```